# MySql store multiple references for another table inside one cell and select it?

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have two tables

```
table: people 

id name goods_owned
1  john   1,4,3
2  Mike   2,5
3  Sam    1,5,2
4  Andy   5,3,4
```

-

```
table goods:

  g_id g_name  g_class
    1   sugar  food
    2   salt   food
    3   boat   transp
    4   house  habitation
    5   car    transp
```

this is simple example of table `goods` its actually very long and each person in `people` can have multiple `goods` assigned to him e.g. car, boat, sugar etc there is no limitation of how much one person can have and its totally random. I could not find better way to store it than coma separated e.g. `1,5,3`

I am having the problem making selection i need to have e.g.

```
SELECT people.*, goods.name
   FROM people
      LEFT JOIN  goods ON goods.g_id = people.goods_owned
         WHERE name = "Sam"
```

However problem is goods_owned has multiple ID's of goods in cell and they need to be somehow broken down to get answer:

```
1, Sam, sugar, car, salt
```

If you know better alternative to storing (e.g 100) multiple values coma separated in one cell, then please let me know.

Comment: bad bad bad table design, normalise your data. add goods_owned table people_id, good_id, one row per good

Comment: Also - bad bad bad table design, normalise your data. add goods_owned table people_id, good_id, one row per good :)

Comment: Read up on many-to-many relations, you need it here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A person can be related to zero, one or more goods.
A good can be related to zero, one or more people.

That's a many-to-many relationship.

Normally, we handle this by creating a third table, which is a "relationship" that points to the other two tables

```
table: goods_owned
people_id goods_id
        1        1
        1        4
        1        3
        2        2
        2        5
        3        1
        3        5
        3        2
        4        5
        4        3
        4        4
```

The combination of these two columns can be specified as unique, and can serve as the primary key for the table.  Each column can be defined as a foreign key to the parent tables.

```
CREATE TABLE goods_owned
( people_id  INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
, goods_id   INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
, PRIMARY KEY (people_id, goods_id)
-- , KEY FK_goods_owned_people (people_id)  -- redundant with PK
, KEY FK_goods_owned_goods (goods_id)
, CONSTRAINT FK_goods_owned_people FOREIGN KEY (people_id) REFERENCES people (id)
, CONSTRAINT FK_goods_owned_goods FOREIGN KEY (goods_id) REFERENCES goods (g_id)
) ;
```

Another alternative, if the set of "goods" is static and well-defined, and doesn't need to be represented in a table, then you could make use of the MySQL SET datatype, and have a single table. But that approach is only suitable if the set is static (won't need to be changed.)

Comment: Should also add a unique `id` as primary key, auto-increment for your table example.

Comment: Great thanks. i know that i did this before like that, its just today i been kind of brain dead. Its hard to see the alternative when you have to rebuild all your original layout you usually try to find solution for what you have. And it all started with one good per person so i put it in the same table.

Comment: @JTSmith, why? you can add a key on the 2 fields to achieve the same result

Comment: @JT Smith: An id column isn't necessary. The combination of the two foreign keys can serve as the primary key.  If this table were to contain additional columns (recording information beyond the existence of a relationship), then I agree with you, and would opt to add an anonymous ID value.

Answer (score 2):

Your database is not normalized. You have [repeating groups within columns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form#Repeating_groups_within_columns). You should normalize your database if at all possible.

If you can't change your database design you can use [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set), but it will be sloooooooow:

```
SELECT people.id, people.name, people.goods_owned, goods.name
FROM people
LEFT JOIN goods ON FIND_IN_SET(goods.g_id, people.goods_owned)
WHERE name = 'Sam'
```

Comment: Thx for the FIND_IN_SET i did not know about it

Comment: BTW...thanks for that "if you can't change your database...".  I often ask a question and get many answers that assume I have the luxury of redesigning everything from the application to the network architecture, lol.

Answer (score 1):

Let's just I was really bored...

```
CREATE TABLE `people` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
;
CREATE TABLE `goods` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `class_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
;
CREATE TABLE `goods_owned` (
  `people_id` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `goods_id` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MYISAM CHARSET=latin1
;
CREATE TABLE `classes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `class_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
;

INSERT INTO `people` (`id`, `name`) VALUES('1','John');
INSERT INTO `people` (`id`, `name`) VALUES('2','Mike');
INSERT INTO `people` (`id`, `name`) VALUES('3','Sam');
INSERT INTO `people` (`id`, `name`) VALUES('4','Andy');

INSERT INTO `classes` (`id`, `class_name`) VALUES('1','Food');
INSERT INTO `classes` (`id`, `class_name`) VALUES('2','Trans');
INSERT INTO `classes` (`id`, `class_name`) VALUES('3','Habitation');

INSERT INTO `goods` (`id`, `name`, `class_id`) VALUES('1','Sugar','1');
INSERT INTO `goods` (`id`, `name`, `class_id`) VALUES('2','Salt','1');
INSERT INTO `goods` (`id`, `name`, `class_id`) VALUES('3','Boat','2');
INSERT INTO `goods` (`id`, `name`, `class_id`) VALUES('4','House','3');
INSERT INTO `goods` (`id`, `name`, `class_id`) VALUES('5','Car','2');

INSERT INTO `goods_owned` (`people_id`, `goods_id`) VALUES('1','1');
INSERT INTO `goods_owned` (`people_id`, `goods_id`) VALUES('1','4');
INSERT INTO `goods_owned` (`people_id`, `goods_id`) VALUES('1','3');
INSERT INTO `goods_owned` (`people_id`, `goods_id`) VALUES('2','2');
INSERT INTO `goods_owned` (`people_id`, `goods_id`) VALUES('2','5');
INSERT INTO `goods_owned` (`people_id`, `goods_id`) VALUES('3','1');
INSERT INTO `goods_owned` (`people_id`, `goods_id`) VALUES('3','5');
INSERT INTO `goods_owned` (`people_id`, `goods_id`) VALUES('3','2');
INSERT INTO `goods_owned` (`people_id`, `goods_id`) VALUES('4','5');
INSERT INTO `goods_owned` (`people_id`, `goods_id`) VALUES('4','3');
INSERT INTO `goods_owned` (`people_id`, `goods_id`) VALUES('4','4');

SELECT
    people.name
    , goods.name
    , classes.class_name
FROM people
    LEFT JOIN goods_owned ON (people.id = goods_owned.people_id)
    LEFT JOIN goods ON (goods_owned.goods_id = goods.id)
    LEFT JOIN classes ON (goods.class_id = classes.id)
WHERE classes.id = 1  /*Include only Food Goods*/
ORDER BY people.name;
        ;
```

Comment: +1. Nice job. What about using the InnoDB engine, and specifying the FOREIGN KEY constraints?  If there is a static set of classes, that would be a candidate for the MySQL ENUM (enumeration) datatype, without the need for a separate table.

Comment: Any improvements - I just opened the editor and took defaults, lol

Comment: The Classes are what you described as Food, Habitat, and Transportation.  With a table for that you're able to select/sort by Classes, as well as add/change classes.  e.g. If you wanted to have Planes, Trains, and Automobiles instead of just Transporation, you would add those classes to that table, and change the id that is used in the Goods table for those items.